# Error in spring data neo4j sample when using GraphRepository

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, node-neo4j

Hi i have downloaded one sample code for spring data neo4j. i am facing the below error can someone help on this.

Code snippet:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository<Person> {
    Person findByName(String name);
    Iterable<Person> findByTeammatesName(String name);
}
```

Application.java

```
PersonRepository personRepository = ctx.getBean(PersonRepository.class);
GraphDatabase graphDatabase = ctx.getBean(GraphDatabase.class);

Transaction tx = graphDatabase.beginTx();
try {
    personRepository.save(greg);
    personRepository.save(roy);
    personRepository.save(craig);

    greg = personRepository.findByName("Greg");

    //......

    for (String name: new String[]{greg.name, roy.name, craig.name}) {
            System.out.println(personRepository.findByName(name));
```

Error :

```
The return types are incompatible for the inherited methods PagingAndSortingRepository<Person,Long>.findAll(Sort), CRUDRepository<Person>.findAll(Sort) PersonRepository.java   /SpringDataForNeo4j/src line 5  Java Problem
The return types are incompatible for the inherited methods Repository<Person,Long>.count(), CRUDRepository<Person>.count() PersonRepository.java   /SpringDataForNeo4j/src line 5  Java Problem
The return types are incompatible for the inherited methods Repository<Person,Long>.findAll(), CRUDRepository<Person>.findAll() PersonRepository.java   /SpringDataForNeo4j/src line 5  Java Problem
```

Can someone help me to resolve this please.

Comment: According to the 'error message' your repository is inheriting methods with conflicting return types.  
1) When do you get the error? (When compiling?)  
2) What is on line 5 in your PersonRepository.java?  
3) Where did you get the code? What do you mean by 'one sample code' and which version of SDN are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this exact problem by updating these jars:
(*spring-data-commons* and
*spring-data-commons-core* ) to their latest version.
In any case i think this is a library problem . Go to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data to get the latest jars.